# Moving image vertically and horizontally

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/bxkz186y/

Is there any way to move that cat also 20px up and down during horizontal motion?

My current code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var widthminus = width - 500;
    function goRight() {
        $("#animate").animate({
        left: widthminus
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
      });
    }
    function goLeft() {
        $("#animate").animate({
        left: 0
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goRight, 50);
      });
    }

    setTimeout(goRight, 50);
});
```

Comment: I would suggest CSS animations

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code

Its Move Image All Direction `vertically and horizontally` also

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var widthminus = width - 500;

  function goRight() {
    $("#animate").animate({
      left: widthminus
    }, 5000, function() {
      setTimeout(goDown, 50);
    });
  }

  function goDown() {
    $("#animate").animate({
      top: 50
    }, 5000, function() {
      setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
    });
  }

  function goTop() {
    $("#animate").animate({
      top: 0
    }, 5000, function() {
      setTimeout(goRight, 50);
    });
  }

  function goLeft() {
    $("#animate").animate({
      left: 0
    }, 5000, function() {
      setTimeout(goTop, 50);
    });
  }

  setTimeout(goRight, 50);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is it possible to move it vertically and horizontally at the same time?

Comment: same time only move on one direction not both..!

Comment: @Miyagi you are Girl or Boy

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, to move it in both direction, change both `left` property and `top` property simultaneously:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var widthminus = width - 500;
        function goRight_down() {
            $("#animate").animate({
            left: widthminus,
            top:50
          }, 5000, function() {
             setTimeout(goLeft_up, 50);
          });
        }
        function goLeft_up() {
            $("#animate").animate({
            left: 0,
            top:0
          }, 5000, function() {
             setTimeout(goRight_down, 50);
          });
        }

        setTimeout(goRight_down, 50);
    });
```

```css
.crab {
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="crab">
 <img src="https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/165/76/87490163.jpg" id="animate" class="crab" alt="">
</div>
```